# Convex subcomplexes of CAT(0) cubical complexes

Tags: reference-request, gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, geometric-group-theory, alexandrov-geometry

Is the following statement true?  If so, can anyone provide a reference?

> Let $X$ be a CAT(0) cubical complex, and let $Y$ be a connected
>   subcomplex of $X$.  Then the following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $Y$ is convex in $X$.
> 2. For every cube $C$ in $X$, the intersection $C\cap Y$ is a face of $C$.

Here the empty set is considered a face of every cube, and each cube is a face of itself.

Clearly (1) implies (2), and in all the examples I can think of (2) also implies (1).

Comment: In addition to Anton Petrunin's answer below, maybe also this paper is of interest: http://arxiv.org/abs/1211.1871

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is true.

You condition (2) implies that $X$ is locally convex;
this can be proved the same way as the flag condition for $\mathrm{CAT}[0]$-ness.

It remains to note that for $\mathrm{CAT}[0]$-spaces local convexity + connectedness implies convexity.

Comment: Fantastic!  Do you happen to know of a reference for the fact that condition (2) implies local convexity?

Comment: I would suggest looking at Section 2.2 of this paper: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00039-007-0629-4

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Anton Petrunin's answer, I would like to mention that a more combinatorial argument is possible. Indeed, in a CAT(0) cube complex $X$, a *full* subcomplex $Y$ (i.e. a subcomplex which contains a cube if it already contains its vertices) is convex with respect to the CAT(0) metric if and only if it is convex with respect to the combinatorial metric; see Theorem 2.13 in Haglund's article *Finite index subgroups of graph products*. In other words, it suffices to show that the one-skeleton of $Y$ is convex in $X$ endowed with the graph metric. Now, the proposition is a straightforward consequence of the following two observations:

**Proposition 1:** *Let $X$ be a CAT(0) cube complex and $\alpha,\beta$ two combinatorial paths with the same endpoints. Assume $\beta$ is a geodesic. There exists a sequence of combinatorial paths $\gamma_1=\alpha, \gamma_2,\ldots, \gamma_{n-1},\gamma_n=\beta$ such that, for every $1 \leq i \leq n-1$, $\gamma_{i+1}$ is obtained from $\gamma_i$ by removing a backtrack or flipping a square.*

Here, by *flipping a square*, I mean replacing two consecutive edges of a square by the other two consecutive edges.

**Proposition 2:** *Let $X$ be a CAT(0) cube complex and $\alpha,\beta$ two combinatorial geodesics with the same endpoints. There exists a sequence of combinatorial paths $\gamma_1=\alpha, \gamma_2,\ldots, \gamma_{n-1},\gamma_n=\beta$ such that, for every $1 \leq i \leq n-1$, $\gamma_{i+1}$ is obtained from $\gamma_i$ by flipping a square.*

Proposition 2 is Theorem 4.6 in Sageev's thesis *Ends of group pairs and non-positively curved cube complexes*, and Proposition 1 can be proved similarly. We deduce that:

> Let $X$ be a CAT(0) cube complex and $Y \subset X$ a full subcomplex. Then $Y$ is convex if and only if it is connected and every square containing two consecutive sides in $Y$ lies entirely in $Y$.

Fix two vertices $a,b \in Y$. Because $Y$ is connected, there exists a combinatorial path in $Y$ between $a,b$. As a consequence of Proposition 1, $\alpha$ can be turned into a combinatorial geodesic $\gamma$ in $Y$. As a consequence of Proposition 2, every geodesic between $a$ and $b$ can be obtained from $\gamma$ by flipping squares, and so must lie in $Y$. We conclude that $Y$ is (combinatorially) convex.